# Automatically format Excel Table WITHOUT dragging cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, unique, transpose

I have transposed unique values from sheet 1 into sheet 2.

Sheet1:

```
Column A
1
1
2
2
2
3
3
3

Sheet2:
COLUMN 1------------COLUMN 2------------COLUMN 3
---1x------------------2x------------------3x----
```

The table in sheet 2 is formatted in a table with formulas....however if a a new column is added for example column D..... the table wont automatically format UNLESS i dragg the formula across - is there a way to automatically format this????

```
Sheet2:
Column A------------Column B------------Column C      Column D        Column E
--- 1x------------------2x------------------3x
```

Column D and E will remain blank unless unless I drag the cells across -- how can I automate this process?

Comment: Why not convert your simple table to excel table?

Comment: What kind of formatting you want? Please specify?

Comment: You create a table in Excel by selecting your data and `ctrl + t`